# LSTM, multiple input : 3 day * (array with 136 elements + 2 integer)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to build LSTM model that predict single categorical output using last three days input data.
For the input data, one day observation has 1 array of size 136 with boolean type and 2 integers which related to the observation datetime.

Without observation datetime, I tried model like this

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, batch_input_shape = (1,3,136), stateful=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(28,activation='softmax'))
```

However, the result was quite not good. The training result image is below.

(Please click the hyperlink)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZNaf.png)

So I have two questions for this model.

First, is this correct way with the three arrays? Second, what is the proper way to use arrays and integer data?

Comment: Is there a reason why you only have a single LSTM cell?

Comment: There's no specific reason. I just tried the basic one. Is it better for multilayer??

Comment: I think if you added 2 LSTM cells, each one with a dropout layer after it, it would help minimise the overfitting you're experiencing. With that said, I'm not sure why your validation accuracy is so low. Can you provide a link to your code so I can take a look?

Comment: Here's my github. [github](https://github.com/INDIsy/Keras). Also I tried multi-layer LSTM, however the accuracy of training set didn't go up more than 10%. I'll try other way to improve this model and please let me know anything about my code or my model.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I haven't had a chance to run your code yet. I'll take a look tonight :)

Comment: Hi! I re-uploaded the input output files. The code will be run with your 'hdir'(where the input/output data locate) and 'wdir'(where the result images saved) :)

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit snowed under with work at the moment so I don't have time to check your code- sorry :( Maybe try re-uploading this question so someone else can have a crack at it

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll do that with more developed version :)